# JavaScript foreach Key Value array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have just this array :

```
var sArray = {856:"users", 857:"avatars", 858:"emails"};
```

and I want to use `forEach` in a way to get key and value from that:

```
key = 856
value = user
```

My `$.each` code doesn't return the result I'm expecting, and I get instead:

```
856:user
```

I must be separate that with `:` to get key and value from this array.

My code is:

```
$.each(template_array, function(key, value) {
    console.log("key: " + "value: " + value);
});
```

How to access key and value without separate?

Comment: You have `"value: " + value`, why not `"key: " + key`

Comment: I think issue is in your array, is this the exact code you are using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just take `Object.keys` for the keys and `Array.prototype.forEach` for the values in plain Javascript.

```js
var sArray = { 856: 'users', 857: 'avatars', 858: 'emails'};

Object.keys(sArray).forEach(function (key) {
    document.write('key: ' + key + ', value: ' + sArray[key] + '<br>');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just concatenate them using `+`

```js
var template_array = {
  856: 'users',
  857: 'avatars',
  858: 'emails'
};
$.each(template_array, function(key, value) {
  console.log('key:' + key + ', value:' + value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**UPDATE :**
I think you have an array then use the following code

```js
var template_array = ['856: users',
  '857: avatars',
  '858: emails'
];

template_array.forEach(function(v) {
  v = v.split(':');
  console.log('key:' + v[0] + ', value:' + v[1]);
});
```

Comment: result is `0:856:users
1:857:avatars
2:858:emails` i want to have `key: 856 , value: users` your code is not correct

Comment: @mahdipishguy : check the second snippet

Comment: The second snippet is exactly what the question asks not to have to do "I must be separate that with : to get key and value from this array."

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
var template_array = {
   856: 'users',
   857: 'avatars',
   858: 'emails'
};
var date = [];
$.each(template_array,function (key , val){ 
   date.push({key:key, value:val})
 });

console.log(date)
```

Comment: @mahdi pishguy: try this one

Answer (score 0):

```js
var template_array = {
  856: 'users',
  857: 'avatars',
  858: 'emails'
};
for (key in template_array) {
  console.log('key:' + key + ', value:' + template_array[key]);
});
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes